# Ruby/Rails: How can I replace a string with data from an array of objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, string

I have two bits of data I'm working with here.

A "question": `This is an [example] string for [testing] and [what not].`

And then I have an array of objects (called "answers") from my database:

```
[#<Answer id: 137, question_id: 207, text: "example">, #<Answer id: 138, question_id: 207, text: "testing">, #<Answer id: 139, question_id: 207, text: "what not"]
```

What I need to do is replace the bracketed text in the question (`[example]`) with a link containing data from the corresponding object.

So `[example]` might become `<a href="#" data-answer="137" data-question="207">example</a>`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you know beforehand what answers to use or do you first have to extract the bracketed text and then search the database?

Comment: I have the answers beforehand.

Comment: Since `Answer` is your custom class, you have tell how to access the id and the question id in an `Answer` instance. Otherwise, it's impossible to answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Assuming you have the answers already:**

```
str = "This is an [example] string for [testing] and [what not]."
answers.each{|o| str.gsub!("[#{o.name}]", "<a href=\"#\" data-answer=\"#{o.id}\" data-question=\"#{o.question_id}\">#{o.name}</a>")}
```

**If you don't have the answers:**

```
str = "This is an [example] string for [testing] and [what not]."
m =  str.scan(/\[([^\]]*)\]/).map{|s|s[0]}
Answer.where(:text => m).each{|o| str.gsub!("[#{o.name}]", "<a href=\"#\" data-answer=\"#{o.id}\" data-question=\"#{o.question_id}\">#{o.name}</a>")}
```

This works by using regex to search for all the text inbetween the [] brackets, which then returns an array to m. This array consists of ["example", "testing", "what not"].

You then pass that array into the where() call, which internally has SQL use an IN expression, such as `WHERE text IN ('example','testing', 'what not')`

After running this, str is now changed to your desired result.

Comment: ?? I've been busy writing that for the last 5 or so minutes. (I actually created an Answers model ^_^)

Comment: Very true. Honestly I'll be in the create answer page for a couple minutes, and when I submit the answer.. I see someone already had a simliar answer. Sorry for the mixup, Kelly.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to have to get the whole table from the database, you can search for those bracketed strings first, then perform a search on the database:

```
str = "This is an [example] string for [testing] and [what not]."
matches =  str.scan(/\[([^\]]*)\]/).collect { |s|s[0]}
Answer.where( :text => matches).each{|o| str.gsub!("[#{o.name}]", "<a href=\"#\" data-answer=\"#{o.id}\" data-question=\"#{o.question_id}\">#{o.name}</a>")}
```

Comment: I would just suggest using %Q{} so you don't have to escape all of the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "This is an [example] string for [testing] and [what not]"
 => "This is an [example] string for [testing] and [what not]" 
h = {id: 137, question_id: 207, text: "example"}
 => {:id=>137, :question_id=>207, :text=>"example"} 

s.sub(/\[example\]/, %Q{<a href="#" data-answer="#{h[:id]}" data-question="#{h[:question_id]}">#{h[:text]}</a>})
 => "This is an <a href=\"#\" data-answer=\"137\" data-question=\"207\">example</a> string for [testing] and [what not]"
```